# undescore.js pluck & concat

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is it possible to concatenate plucked array properties with a one-liner using underscore.js ?

e.g.

```
var foos = [{bars: [1,2,3]}, {bars: [4,5]}];
_.pluck(foos, "bars") // returns [[1,2,3],[4,5]]; me wants [1,2,3,4,5]
```

N.B. "bars" are also objects in my case in case it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `flatten`.

With native JS, you can use:

```
foos.map(it => it.bars).reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c), []);
```

or with underscore/lodash, you can use:

```
_.flatten(_.pluck(foos, "bars"))
```